# Why does System.Int32 take 24 bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

If an `int` takes 4 bytes, why does `System.Int32` takes 24 bytes when boxing an integer into an object?

For example:

```
int i = 3;
object o = i;
```

Comment: exactly _how_ do you get those numbers?

Comment: I'm curious how you are measuring your 24 bytes (you don't show that).  The name `o` is an object variable (i.e., a reference to a reference type instance), so the object it refers to (the boxed int) gets allocated on the managed heap and `o` ends up being a reference type variable that holds a reference to that object

Comment: "boxing" means putting the value type into an object box. It's not just a cast: it effectively adds a pointer and other trappings involved in having a full object reference. In other words, the box itself has some overhead.

Comment: Are you drawing a distinction between `int` and `System.Int32` with that wording?

Answer (score 16):

In C#/CLR reference types have [some size overhead](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/):

> The layout of a managed object is pretty simple: a managed object contains instance data, a pointer to a meta-data (a.k.a. method table pointer) and a bag of internal information also known as an object header.

[image]

So when you box your `int` into the heap it will be stored as a reference type and will include all the extra info and then the memory will be aligned resulting in something like this:

```
Object Header (8 bytes)
Method Table Pointer (8 bytes)
Int (4 bytes)
padding (4 bytes, to align at 8 bytes)
```

Note that this is dependent on the bitness of the process (the breakdown above is for  64-bit case) and is actually runtime implementation detail (the previously linked article mentions at least one implementation that [differs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/abhinaba/wp7-clr-managed-object-overhead#general-layout)).

Comment: Correct, but it is really an implementation detail of the runtime. You know the boxed value will have a header etc., but exactly how big that header is, is an implementation detail. Also, not include above, is the size of the _reference_ itself, i.e. the "number" (suposedly) which act as some sort of address to tell where the box is located. Again an implementation detail, but the reference could be a 32-bit or a 64-bit number.

Comment: My private implementation of .NET uses pen and paper, and each byte is written in cuneiform. It is a perfect implementation of ECMA-335, but does not use 24 bytes for an `int32`. Now what? We shouldn't really care where or how our data is stored in memory, or even if it exists. It could be on the moon for it should make a difference

Comment: "Now what? We shouldn't really care where or how our data is stored in memory, or even if it exists. It could be on the moon for it should make a difference." @charlieface Why should we learn to do arithmetic when we can just use a calculator? What a terrible message to send a curious person trying to better understand how a computer works under the hood.

Comment: @PeterMoore It wasn't to say that we shouldn't learn, we *should* learn how implementations and abstractions work, but that we should also be aware that it's *completely* implementation-defined. This is a good answer, but the point in the the [first comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658702/why-does-system-int32-take-24-bytes/70658757?noredirect=1#comment124910604_70658757) by needs to be stressed more. Otherwise beginners will think: this is how it *always* works, when that is absolutely not the case