# What is the layout of a reference type in .NET

Tags: .net, .net-core

From C# 9.0 in a Nutshell, Chapter 2, Type Basics, Storage Overhead

> Reference types require separate allocations of memory for the reference and object.
> The object consumes as many bytes as its fields, plus additional administrative over‐
> head. The precise overhead is intrinsically private to the implementation of
> the .NET runtime, but at minimum, the overhead is 8 bytes, used to store a key to
> the object’s type as well as temporary information such as its lock state for multi‐
> threading and a flag to indicate whether it has been fixed from movement by the
> garbage collector. Each reference to an object requires an extra 4 or 8 bytes, depend‐
> ing on whether the .NET runtime is running on a 32- or 64-bit platform.

On .NET 6 on my 64-bit machine it is indeed two words of overhead, 16 bytes. I am wondering what exactly is contained in that administrative part. One word will be the pointer to a vtable. What's the other one?

I know this is a volatile implementation detail that can vary between runtimes. **I am specifically interested in the [`dotnet/runtime`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) CLR at  the time of writing**. In particular, can you point me to where in the CLR code this is defined? Is there some .NET documentation that explains it? Any notes on how this changed between .NET Framework, .NET Core and now unified .NET are appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70658757/2501279) answer can shed some light. As for dos - have not seen those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Comments at the top of `class object`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0266f034221188bc7d0156ba76a571c71885c68f/src/coreclr/vm/object.h#L119) in `object.h` (for dotnet/runtime on GitHub) say

```cpp
// The only fields mandated by all objects are
//
//     * a pointer to the code:MethodTable at offset 0
//     * a poiner to a code:ObjHeader at a negative offset. This is often zero.  It holds information that
//         any addition information that we might need to attach to arbitrary objects.
```

Only `m_pMethTab` is actually declared, as the header is implicit in the layout.

So there is the `MethodTable`, which is used for vtable lookups, and the `ObjHeader` which appears to be used for synchronization mechanisms. Both are effectively `IntPtr` sized.

---

Furthermore, there are compiler constants which rule over the layout

```cpp
#ifdef TARGET_64BIT
#define OBJHEADER_SIZE      (sizeof(DWORD) /* m_alignpad */ + sizeof(DWORD) /* m_SyncBlockValue */)
#else
#define OBJHEADER_SIZE      sizeof(DWORD) /* m_SyncBlockValue */
#endif

// The generational GC requires that every object be at least 12 bytes
// in size.

#define MIN_OBJECT_SIZE     (2*TARGET_POINTER_SIZE + OBJHEADER_SIZE)
```