# Is it better to group by collection or get data from that collection by batches in c#

Tags: c#

I have a rather theoretical question, let us say I have a collection with large amounts of records of model that would look like:

```
public class Model
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

there are millions or even billions of records in this collection, and there can be couple of same timestamps with different value.

1 **Group whole collection** like some operations on that collection according to timestamp (for the heck of it let us assume I need to analize data by 1 minute timespan, so key of that grouping would be like "2023-01-01T00:01:00", "2023-01-01T00:02:00", ... etc) and value would be well aggregated values for that particular timestamp (that first value will be values between "2023-01-01T00:00:00" and "2023-01-01T00:01:00" and so on).

2 **Get some scaling** - like I can process data by hour so I get data from original collection iterating "2023-01-01T00:00:00" and "2023-01-01T01:00:00" and do grouping it by the minute and do some processing, next "2023-01-01T01:00:00" and "2023-01-01T02:00:00" and so on. so in conclusion I can do operations those small batches and keep some in between state on cache.

First one is easier but second is more efficient I think. So what is best case scenario for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(would be a mess in comments and text length doesn't allow for this)

A third option your data design is wrong from the start? For a second, think this is a collection of real time sensor data where data is collected per second. For a specific sensor, you would end up with 86400 rows per day, in a year over 31 million rows, 10 years oh well.

Looking from this perspective, your bottleneck is in getting the data from the source in the first place. Indexes wouldn't help you at all and it would be slow anyways whether you do that in 1 minute or 1 hour spans. You would just be spreading the analysis part, but data retrieval would still be your enemy.

IOW, just try creating such data for 5-10 years and querying it without even doing any calculation.

Now, how you might solve it? On C# side, operations would be fast. Then maybe you can redesign it on database side? ie:
Instead of:

Datetime, Int (resolution down to second)

```
2023-01-01T00:01:00, 1
2023-01-01T00:01:01, 7
...
```

Your data might be:

Date, varbinary(MAX) && if it were SQL server

```
2023-01-01, < your data as a single binary value 86400*4 bytes >
```

This makes it much easier on the storage side. For a 10 years data you would be getting less than 3660 rows. Processing this on C# side would be fast, be it sequential or dividing it into some group of dates and async computation.

I know it looks weird, but model and try (I did before, for some sensor data).

Note: This assumes, for a given second there is only one value. Resulting data size is much smaller than original datetime, int version.

Answer (score 2):

> or even billions of records in this collection

If I have counted correctly just to only store 1 billion of such records you will need ~30 GB of memory (in x64 process, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658702/why-does-system-int32-take-24-bytes/70658757#70658757)). You can reduce this size by half using `struct`'s but still it is quite a lot (there are also some other considerations) and still this can be not scalable enough.

Depended on the actual use case there are different possibilities but to process big amounts of data it is far better to use heavy parallel/distributed approaches. You can either develop your own system or use one of the existing (see map-reduce, Apache Ignite, Apache Spark, Presto/Trino, etc.).

Also based on the data structure potentially you can leverage using [time series database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database).

Also you can just store already aggregated data (with less precision) calculating/updating corresponding aggregates on data ingestion (or with some background processing).